# Mass file renaming - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have many files in a folder with this format

```
constant_blah_blah_blah.png
```

How can I replace the underscores with spaces and also remove the constant_ from them using PowerShell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't tried anything. I have no idea how PowerShell works.

Comment: You should try working it out with searches on here, Google, and/or looking at the Powershell documentation on MSDN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
Get-childItem constant* | % {rename-item $_.name ($_.name -replace '_',' ')}
Get-childItem constant* | % {rename-item $_.name ($_.name -replace 'constant ','')}
```

Comment: This will do two renames, though, which isn't necessary (see my answer).

Answer (score 7):

```
# gather all files that match the criteria
Get-ChildItem constant_* |
   ForEach-Object {
      # remove the "constant_" from the beginning and replace _ by space.
      Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name -replace '^constant_' -replace '_', ' ')
   }
```

Or shorter:

```
ls constant_* | %{rni $_ ($_.Name -replace '^constant_' -replace '_', ' ')}
```

Comment: +1 for the filtering and expanding ls / %.